# Issues with installing linux based OS on my laptop

Tags: linux, installation

Hello there fellow users, as of late i have been facing a rather weird issue. I have been trying to install linus os, as of late. I have tried mint and ubuntu but they both fail to install as a secondary os. And then i tried installing phoenixOS, but that also gave an issue. For using U drive(portable media), the pc will not pick up the drive, and boot to windows. When installed on the hard drive, its always stuck at some preset values, with a sigma sign at the end. I have a very old laptop utilising intel atom n455 chip. Do i have to shrink a volume as a seperate drive and try that, or is there some configuration issues that prevents me from installing them? Is it simply not compatible with linux based platforms? Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!
P.S i am rather new to try linux and i have my reasons to go to phoenix. Also, any ways to unlock my bios would be appreciated.

Comment: What's a "U drive"? How are you preparing the installation media? What laptop is it exactly? Does it support 64bit OSes? Are you using BIOS (legacy) or UEFI boot? (please [edit] the question)

Comment: @gronostaj U drive as in portable media. My chip supports 64 bit OSes. But right now im trying to figure out the BIOS. I cant tell if its on legacy or UEFI boot. Maybe its locked

Comment: How are you preparing the installation media? What laptop is it exactly?

Comment: Hello gronostaj, im preparing it on a thinkpad s10-3 and using a bootable media like usb. I have been constantly getting boot failure when i try to do a live install on a usb

Comment: So _how_ are you preparing it? What tool are you using? What settings, if any?

Comment: @gronostaj im using rufus iso mode to prepare it. The OS also has its own tool for live usbs, but it still gave issues. I'm convinced that its probably my bios not set to legacy mode. I dont even have that setting in bios.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of Rufus window with all settings set, just before creation of the installation USB ([edit] the post).